# FileStream throwing UnauthorisedAccessException - C#

Tags: c#, filestream, unauthorized

I am trying to create a FileStream but keep getting "UnauthorisedAccessException",   what is wrong with this statement?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Thanks,

Eamonn

Comment: @JonEgerton: "Doc, it hurts when I do *this*..."

Comment: Microsoft didn't add a Windows error code for "Cannot open directory as a file", they probably didn't think it to be necessary.  The "access denied" error code doesn't help a great deal though.  Never write files to the root directory, your customer will still get the same exception.  Now accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to open a file stream that points to the root directory of your C partition. I assume, that's not what you want to do. If you want to create a file, than specify a file name.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to open a directory as a file.

Answer (score 3):

I think the path should be a filename - "c:\test.txt" rather than the location.

Also watch that c:\ is available, depending on the OS it can be protected (eg in Vista/Win 7)